# How to compile/build and package an MSIX project but in parallel?

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, msix, winui

I'm trying to create an msixbundle or an msixupload file that will be uploaded to the Microsoft Store. Currently I'm using Azure Pipelines to perform the build, which targets x86|x64. I now want to add ARM64, but the builds are taking longer than the 60 minute limit in Azure Pipelines.

So, I'm trying to figure out how to parallelize the MSIX build and packaging process. Right now, each architecture is built sequentially. How do I parallelize this but also bundle the different architectures into an msixbundle?

I've read this blog on how to parallelize the architecture builds, but it states at the very end that this does not include the bundling step. In fact, if you try to add the bundling step, the process is not parallelized. https://www.sharpgis.net/post/Speeding-up-multi-architecture-compilation-by-parallelizing-your-build

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.